# How to gsub with wild characters (for spaces)

Tags: ruby, regex, gsub

I need to replace combo of 2 words with another combo disregarding any number of spaces between them, is it possible to do with any kind of wildcards in single line ?

```
text.gsub(/Create Proc/i,"Delete Proc")      ## single space
text.gsub(/Create  Proc/i,"Delete Proc")     ## 2 spaces
text.gsub(/Create   Proc/i,"Delete Proc")    ## 3 spaces
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
text.gsub(/Create\s+Proc/i,"Delete Proc")
```

the `\s` escape code will match on whitespace (spaces and tabs)

http://rubular.com/r/0bqvUBnojC